# Prince xml doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, princexml

Ive created a test page to test using Prince xml but this code doesn't seem to work.

**index.php**

```
require_once("prince.php");

$prince = new Prince('www1.must.edu.ph/tts/prince/Engine/bin/prince.exe');
$prince->setHTML(true);

$html = file_get_contents("reportHeader.html");

$ret = $prince->convert_string_to_file($html,'www1.must.edu.ph/tts/prince/Engine/bin/pink.pdf');

echo $html;

if($ret)
echo "converted";
else
echo "not";
```

whenever I access the page, there is no error.. it just displays the echoed $html and 'not'..

Comment: @ShivanRaptor thats the problem..It doesn't displays any error..It will just echo not..

Comment: The syntax is not readily available online, but I think `convert_string_to_file` is the problem - it can only write to a local PDF, and you're trying to write to a URL.

Comment: @halfer i have the access to its server and even if I write the whole path it still doesn't work..

Comment: OK, please update your code with the changes you've recently made - I take it you've fixed "problem 2" as pointed out by Shivan below?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

I spotted the problem. You run PHP code in an `.html` ? Change the file extension to `.php` and re-upload to PHP-enabled hosting server & retry.

**Problem 2:**

The constructor does not set correctly. The constructor requires an absolute path on server, instead of an URL. The `readme.html` already mentioned this. It should look like:

```
$prince = new Prince('/usr/local/bin/prince');
```

In read me, it said:

> On Windows, be sure to specify the path to the `prince.exe` file located
>   within the `Engine\bin` subfolder of the Prince installation.

**Note:** Most of the PHP-enabled hosting server are NOT Windows-based; even it's Windows-based, it won't allow you to execute `.exe` .

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, so I used SSH to access my server and realized that I did not have a font library installed.  If you are using something like CentOS, then you will need to install a font library first. I found this helpful http://blog.whatgeek.com.pt/2011/11/10/install-core-fonts-centos-6/

Answer (score 0):

Running Prince on a virtual box on my Mac using the YesLogic PHP wrapper and parsing the PHP files with a web browser. No PDF output, no errors reported by the wrapper.

The answers above didn't resolve the issue for me.

So I parsed the PHP files from the command line using **'php -f index.php'** and it worked. Stupid mistake on my part - my PHP files simply didn't have the correct permissions.